# An alias defined in a bash script does not work within the same script

Tags: bash, posix, alias

I have a simple bash script.

```
alias myls=ls
myls
```

If I execute this script, I get an error.

```
$ bash foo.sh 
foo.sh: line 2: myls: command not found
```

- Why does the alias not work in the script?
- Does this behavior conform to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/)?
- If it is indeed not supposed to work, could you please point me to an authoritative documentation that stays this?

Answer (score 2):

See `man bash`:

> Aliases  are  not  expanded  when  the  shell  is  not  interactive,  unless   the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`